# how to instantiate/ show a TableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I am struggling with this awful project for two weeks now and nothing seems to work. I have to do an app that loads some words from a server and presents them as pins on a map(MKView). I have to cluster the pins when the user zooms-out and for that I have used a this-party library written in Objective-C, but I also had to make a custom callout view with a button. When the user presses the said button the app should go to a TableViewController and here is my problem: I can't make it to do it. I have used before the "performSegueWIthIdentifier" and it worked very well, but now I get the error "there is no segue with '---' identifier". I know there are many other threads with this, but none of the solutions there work for me. Moreover, I have tried to instantiate the ViewController programmatically, but this does not work either because I get the "unexpectedly found nil..." and I don't know what to do any more.

I know I am doing something wrong, most probably how I call these functions, but I don't know what. This is what I have tried until now:

in the .xib file I have this:

```
import UIKit

class MarkerInfoView: MKAnnotationView {

    @IBOutlet weak var theButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func readIt(sender: AnyObject) {
        ViewController.goToArticles()
    }

}
```

and in the ViewController:

```
class func goToArticles(){
        ViewController().reallyGoToArticles()

    }
```

I did this because I could not find another way to be able to call performSegueWithIdentifier or presentViewController

```
func reallyGoToArticles(){
        println("let's go!")

        let theArticlesSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = theArticlesSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("theArticles") as! articlesViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showArticles", sender: self)

    }
```

I have uncommented both options just to show you.

I have uploaded the project [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=dc4a98386752a33f!38239&authkey=!AKiP--ZrLSMb3Jw&ithint=file%2Czip)

Thank you very much!

### Update

I forgot to mention that if I put the line

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showArticles", sender: self)
```

in viewDidLoad it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your project and found your issue.
In `MarkerInfoView.swift`, you call `ViewController.goToArticles()` which is a class function:

```
class func goToArticles(){
        ViewController().reallyGoToArticles()
    }
```

This class function creates a NEW instance of `ViewController` which has nothing to do with the storyboard (and is not aware of segues).
You have to call `self.reallyGoToArticles()` from an instance method like

```
func goToArticles(){
            self.reallyGoToArticles()
        }
```

You have to manage to call the existing `ViewController` from your `MarkerInfoView`

**EDIT:** Here is how to achieve it
MarkerInfoView.swift

```
class MarkerInfoView: MKAnnotationView {

    var vc: ViewController!
    @IBOutlet weak var placePhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var theButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func readIt(sender: AnyObject) {
        vc.goToArticles()
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView annotation: MKAnnotationView!)
    {
        if let pin = annotation.annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation{

            if var infoView = UIView.viewFromNibName("MarkerInfoView") as? MarkerInfoView {
                infoView.nameLabel.text = pin.theTitle
                infoView.detailsLabel.text = pin.theDetails
                infoView.vc = self
                infoView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.width/2, self.view.bounds.height/2)

                self.view.addSubview(infoView)

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
func goToArticles(){
        self.reallyGoToArticles()
    }
```

Comment: and how do I call a method from another file? That is the only way I found possible from I searched

Comment: You have to set a property that will keep a reference to your ViewController. And you set this property when you instantiate your view

Comment: You are welcome ! Keep in mind that every time you instantiate an object (in any language), it will be a new one, different from the other ones and not aware of the modification applied on the others.